# Camera Move and Rotate Follow Player very jerky

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I make a character move on the surface of a circle. I let the camera move and rotate follow character. But the camera move and rotate very jerky. If I increase the value of the third parameter, the shock increases. and to reduce the value of the third parameter, the camera does not rotate to keep up the character. Help me fix it

My Code Camera Follow Player

```
public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    GameController gc;
    public float speed = 2;
    Vector3 pos = new Vector3 (0, 0, -10);
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        gc = FindObjectOfType (typeof(GameController)) as GameController;
    }
    void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        if (gc.gameState == GameController.GameState.playing || gc.gameState == GameController.GameState.changeWave) {
            transform.position = player.position + pos;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp (transform.rotation, 
                                                   player.transform.rotation, 
                                                   speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the position of a transform inside of `FixedUpdate` is a red flag for sure, especially when you're reporting that it's "jerky".  Fixed update happens at an irregular interval compared to the frames displayed.  This is because Physics needs to update using a fixed time step.  The reason why this is the case is out of scope for this question.

Long story short, try changing `FixedUpdate` to `Update` and that should fix things looking "jerky".

Let me know if this doesn't work and I'll look for other possible causes.

Comment: i have changed FixedUpdate to Update but looking jerky.Actually I do not worry about the movement of the camera to the character. My problem about the rotation of the camera on the character (it is very jerky)

Comment: Okay so I've found what looks to be the problem.  You aren't Slerping properly.  The third parameter of the Slerp function call is the ratio between the start point and the end point.  For instance, if you wanted to move to the middle orientation between the first quaternion and the second quaternion passed to the function, you would pass in the float the value `0.5f`to the function as the third parameter.

Comment: Oh!. I've checked my game. Initially when my player start the game with rotation Z is 0. When I scroll right angles Z is 360 (that's when jerky camera) and start descending. I think the sudden change of rotation Z has made jerky camea

Comment: The only time when the rotation Z  is 0 switch rotation Z is 360 and opposite make jerky camera

Comment: How i can fix that :(

Comment: Like I had stated previously, the way you're miss using the Slerp function can cause the jerky behavior.  The reason is that the third parameter is not a speed, it is a ratio.  Because you are multiplying a constant by a variable number (deltaTime), it will slightly change the ratios value each frame, leading to jerky rotations.

Fix this by removing Slerp and explicitly setting the rotation:
`transform.rotation = player.transform.rotation;`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Rigidbody2D to move the character, make sure to set its Interpolate property to 'Interpolate'. This should fix it.